# How to disable internet connectivity for a particular app/software?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, internet-connection, windows-firewall, steam

I want to disable the internet connectivity of 'Steam' as my younger brother keeps on downloading video games from the Steam client on my computer. I cannot downright uninstall it as well since his existing games would cease to function for the offline mode. So is there a way where the computer is connected to the internet but only 'Steam' is unable to access it?

For reference, we can disable internet connectivity for particular apps on Android smartphones using app settings. Is there a way for doing something like this on a Windows 8.1 PC?

Comment: You can only be “offline” from Steam for a period of time, before those Steam, will refuse to run those applications.  Your better off limiting the amount the device can download at the router level but that requires a router that supports that feature.  At the end of the day this is a social problem and not really a technical problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, you are right. This is a social problem and not a technical one per se. My desktop which sits at home is easily accessible to my brother and I am not at home all the time. It isn't feasible for me to keep a watch over him all the time. But I would like add that nearly every technical problem had normal social level origins as everything we do develop tends to cater to our needs which minimizes physical effort on our part.

Comment: Connect to a software firewall ran on hardware that has the ability to limit bandwidth to certain devices based on the amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows Firewall (`wf.msc`) to create a rule that prevents Steam from accessing the network/internet.

https://www.wikihow.com/Block-a-Program-with-Windows-Firewall

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to go about it?

Comment: @DhruvSinghania there are tons of howtos, e.g. here: https://www.wikihow.com/Block-a-Program-with-Windows-Firewall